# Azure website unloading event though Always On set to true

Tags: iis, azure, nopcommerce

I am hosting a test environment of a nopCommerce 3.5 install on Azurewebsites. I have turned on the Always On feature. As this is a test environment, it is not being hit until I start doing some testing. I noticed that after I come to it after a half hour or so, it is VERY slow to load up. It seems that the home page sometimes comes up in about 8 sec or so, but then if you click on a product, it will take 15 - 20 seconds the first time. From then on out, it is fast.

This problem seems to indicate that the application is unloading from memory as it has gone idle, and then has to spin back up and get loaded into memory again after the period of downtime... standard behaviour for a web app that goes dormant. BUT, the Always On is supposed to prevent that. Any ideas on why I am still experiencing this behaviour?